# HighMaps with two series based on example not working

Tags: javascript, highmaps

I am trying to use the following HighMaps example : http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/all-maps/
In combination with this one : http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/map-bubble/

I want to have a map with coloured zones (like example 1) and mapbubble together.
Unfortunately the code isn't working, the bubble don't get the values from the data source.

```
series : [{
        data : data,
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['fr-all'],
        joinBy: 'hc-key',
        name: 'Circuses',
        allowPointSelect: true,
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.name}'
        }
    },
    {
        data : data,
        type: 'mapbubble',
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['fr-all'],
            minSize: 4,
            maxSize: '12%',
        joinBy: 'hc-key',
        name: 'Clowns',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
            format: '{point.name}',

        }
    }   
    ]
```

Comment: Hi, any chance you can put a JS Fiddle link so we can see what you've tried so far and why it's not working? Are you using the same data array for both series?